# Summary result from referring tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have some database tables.one table call GL and has gl_id, gl_type_id, etc. columns.
Other one is gl_tran table and has gl_id, trn_amount, etc. I want to get a summary of gl_type_id of tran_amount. I wrote a query for this.

```
SELECT GL.CHAT_ACC_ID,GL.CHAT_ACC_NAME,GL.GL_TYPE_ID,GL.GL_TYPE_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'CR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE<'2000-01-01' THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS CR_BEFORE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR='DR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE<'2000-01-01'  THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS DR_BEFORE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'CR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-01-01'  THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS CR_BETWEEN,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'DR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-01-01'  THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS DR_BETWEEN
FROM [COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_MAIN] as GL  
    LEFT JOIN [COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_DAILY_TRN] AS TR ON GL.GL_ID = TR.GL_CODE      
    GROUP BY GL.CHAT_ACC_ID,GL.CHAT_ACC_NAME,GL.GL_TYPE_ID,GL.GL_TYPE_NAME
    ORDER BY GL.GL_ID
```

But this result has only if transaction happens for particular gl. I want summary for all GL.CHAT_ACC_ID. How should I change my query for that result?

Comment: summey? summery? let me suggest something: do not ignore the red underlines provided by the spelling checker.

Comment: OK thanks.I'll correct .

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add below statement in select...

```
Sum(TR.GL_TRN_AMT) over() as TotalSum
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... :D

```
SELECT CG.CHART_ACC_ID,CG.CHART_ACC_NAME,CG.GL_TYPE_ID,CG.GL_TYPE_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'CR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE<'2000-01-01' AND CG.CHART_ACC_ID=GL.CHAT_ACC_ID AND TR.GL_CODE=GL.GL_ID  THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS CR_BEFORE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR='DR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE<'2000-01-01' AND CG.CHART_ACC_ID=GL.CHAT_ACC_ID AND TR.GL_CODE=GL.GL_ID THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS DR_BEFORE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'CR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-01-01' AND CG.CHART_ACC_ID=GL.CHAT_ACC_ID AND TR.GL_CODE=GL.GL_ID THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS CR_BETWEEN,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tr.CR_DR = 'DR' AND TR.BRANCH_CODE=1000 AND TR.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-01-01' AND CG.CHART_ACC_ID=GL.CHAT_ACC_ID AND TR.GL_CODE=GL.GL_ID  THEN TR.GL_TRN_AMT ELSE 0
           END) AS DR_BETWEEN
FROM[COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_DAILY_TRN] AS TR, [COREBANKER1].[dbo].[GL_MAIN] as GL full JOIN  [COREBANKER1].[dbo].GL_CHART_ACC AS CG
     ON GL.CHAT_ACC_ID=CG.CHART_ACC_ID      
    GROUP BY CG.CHART_ACC_ID,CG.CHART_ACC_NAME,CG.GL_TYPE_ID,CG.GL_TYPE_NAME
    ORDER BY CG.CHART_ACC_ID
```